# Can't add Serial Port Component in Windows Form Application. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-6.0

I develop serial portapplication with Windows Form apllication in C#. I am using .Net 6.0.[image: you can see left top.] I want use Serial Port component. I see this component but I can't drag and use this component. You can see screenshot. Can you explain why. And is there a solution?

I tried download serial port library, but it was installed already. I can't use it in design part.

Comment: Try double clicking it in the toolbox

Comment: Do you see the serial port in Device Manager?

Comment: You don't have to add a component to do Serial Port communication. You can create an instance of the class like `SerialPort m_serialPort = new SerialPort();`.

Comment: Add the [System.IO.Ports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/#versions-body-tab) NuGet Package or create a `SerialPort` object in code and let Visual Studio add the package using the Quick Actions -- Won't add a component to the ToolBox, but - as mentioned - it's not really needed

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort doesn't support in .net6.
You should add reference  **System.IO.Ports** from NuGet and then use such as below cod :

```
SerialPort m_serialPort = new SerialPort();
```